# Category based nornalization in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Normalization is done for the entire colum, but how could we do a Category based nornalization in Pandas Dataframe.?

For example,
The given Data has ID,Std,Height.
ID is unique number to identify a student.
Std is Category, PreK ,1,2,..so own.
If we normalize the height,  it would be agnostic on the Std column. It would consider min and max for the complete column of height.

Instead, how could we have the standardized value of height, where the min and max is taken separately for each Std.

Comment: Use groupby('std') to compute min max per std the use that information to normalize?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to group by std

```
df.groupby('std').transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
```

Comment: This is stadarzization..not normalization. But close enough  ,thanks. ( x - x.min()/x.max - x.min() )

Answer (score 1):

Improving @pygirl answer

> Normalization

```
df.groupby('std').transform(lambda x: (x - x.min()) / x.max() - x.min())
```

> Standardization

```
df.groupby('std').transform(lambda x: (x - x.mean()) / x.std())
```